# Should I use api gateway for web application with embedded UI?

Tags: microservices, api-gateway, kong

I have some applications which have UI embedded in Django or ROR app. These applications do not have api but a monolithic web application which have UI and backend in a single module.

All the example I have seen talk about using api gateway for http api. Does it add any value to put such Django or ROR app behind an api gateway?

I am using Kong as api gateway. Not sure if Kong even works with such app. The documentation in Kong only talks about configuring services which are pure api.

If I do not put these applications behind api gateway, then I end up creating a mixed approach where some applications are behind api gateway and some are not. I definitely want to avoid this situation. This makes the whole configuration complex.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with monolithic applications behind a gateway and seems to be a recommended way.

You would benefit from Kong, as it provides different plugins, like Traffic Control or IP Restriction. Also you would have your configurations in a single place. So there are no reasons not to use gateway.

I do not know how your applications are exposed now, but when you will put them behind kong (or proxy) one thing you probably have to look at is client’s request IP: https://discuss.konghq.com/t/how-to-forward-clients-request-ip/384